# Select the attributes of an element that do not have a specified namespace XPath 2.0

Tags: xpath, attributes, xpath-2.0

Just a quick question:

If I have an element say

`<element a:lol="." a:rofl="." b:lol="." b:rofl="." lol="." rofl="."/>`

I know I can select all the attributes under namespace `a` with `@a:*`

How do I select all the attributes without any namespace?

I am aware that `@*[namespace-uri()='']` works, but I was hoping for something more compact - like a keyword prefix. eg: `@none:*`.

Comment: Sadly, you can't - until XPath 3.0, which provides `"":*`.

Comment: There is more than one way to do it -- you may verify that the `name()` is unprefixed (doesn't contain an `':'`, or, alternatively, that the `name()` and `local-name()` are identical.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the extra tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@*[namespace-uri() = '']` seems to me good approach.

Comment: Thanks, couldn't answer my own qu within 8 hours due to my ranking!

Answer (score 1):

**You can also use**:

```
@*[name() eq local-name()]
```

In XPath any unprefixed name is considered to be in "no namespace", therefore this expression selects only unprefixed names, that is, names that are in "no namespace".